# Understanding declarations, malloc, and other parts of this line of C code

Tags: c

I just started working with C and came across a line of code I don't understand.  Could someone explain what it does?

```
short int * work = (short int *) malloc(1000*16);
```

Answer (score 5):

What don't you understand exactly?  The code declares a `short int*` which is a pointer to one or more 16 bit (*at least* 16 bit) signed integers.  It initializes it to a pointer returned by `malloc`, which is a chunk of memory large enough to fit `1000 * 16` bytes.

Now, why did they use `1000 * 16`?  I don't know.  Typically you would allocate along the lines of `num_elements * sizeof(element)`, i.e., `num_elements * sizeof(short int)`.

More canonically, use `num_elements * sizeof(*work)` so that your code doesn't break if you change the type of the pointer.

Also note that [it is a bad idea to cast the return value of malloc in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: short int * work = (short int *) malloc(1000*16);
 
 size_t n;
 while( (n = fread(work, 2, 1000, info.in  )) > 0 )
 {
  
  
  
  fwrite( work, 2, n, info.out );
 }

Comment: @user2113735: ok.  Was that supposed to be a question?

Answer (score 2):

Let's break it down:

- `short int * work`

This declares a pointer to an `int`, called `work`. It's declared as a `short int`, which means that it must be:

- at least 16 bits in length (or two 8 bit bytes), and
- not bigger than a plain `int`.

Generally, shorts are used when an `int` may be too large. Wikipedia has an excellent breakdown of C data types here:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types

- `= (short int *) malloc(1000*16);`

This allocates 1000*16 bytes, and assigns it to the pointer. You can read more about `malloc()` [in the `malloc()` man page](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/malloc/). This particular line is an example of bad style because:

- It's unnecessary to cast the result of malloc - see [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)
- Because the size of a `short int` isn't defined in a standard, this line isn't guaranteed to produce any particular number of `short int`s.

It would be better to instead write:

```
short int * work = malloc(sizeof(short int) * NUMBER_OF_SHORT_INTS_REQUIRED);
```

or, even better:

```
short int * work = malloc(sizeof(work[0]) * NUMBER_OF_SHORT_INTS_REQUIRED);
```

Remember to check to make sure that malloc hasn't returned `NULL` before doing anything with `work`.

Answer (score 2):

You are reserving (dynamically = on run-time) 1000 * 16 = 16000 bytes by using malloc. Using malloc what you get is a pointer to the address of the first byte of the 16000 bytes that have been reserved. You store the result to the pointer that you have for short integers named "work". Typically, every short integer has size 2 bytes, so, essentially malloc has reserved space for 8000 short integers (assuming it succeeded).

If malloc failed to allocate the space, it returns NULL.

Finally, it is bad practice to cast what malloc has returned.

Answer (score 2):

Saw "declarations" in your title.

They have a very good web site for complex declarations. [here](http://cdecl.org/)